# PHP - check the string if contains some of the characters

Tags: php, regex

I have a string which contains some of the following characters (comma is used as OR):

```
$car = (=, !=, <, <=. >, =>)
```

"string $car secondpart"

How can I see which character is used, adn take it in the new variable?

Comment: Better if you provide at least some code that you tried. That will help you understand better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
if (preg_match('/([!<]=|=>?|[<>])/', $car, $m))
   echo $m[1];
```

`$m[1]` will contain one of those string you're looking for.

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yK6jL9/1)

Answer (score 0):

Use this Simple pattern:

```
preg_match("/!=|<=|=>|>|<|=)"/, $string, $matches)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/bA3bG0/1